# I can not show the barchart by ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I do not know why the following message appeared and can not proceed with the command operations.
    'Error: 'decode_colour' is not an exported object from 'namespace:farver''

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsci)
x <- data.frame(
  sample = c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2"),
  weight = c(0.32, 0.33, 0.21, 0.22, 0.37, 0.36)
)

g <- ggplot(x, aes(x = sample, y = weight, fill = sample))
g <- g + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
g <- g + scale_fill_nejm()
plot(g)
```

Thank you so much for considering this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code it outputs the graph and no error appears.
A similar problem was posted [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3642), and running the code there also did not throw an error for me. farver seems to be imported by ggplot2 via scales. Try reinstalling any of those packages and maybe it will solve the issue.

Comment: I reinstall the packages then the problem has gone. Thanx